# Help using LiE computer package?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I'm trying to decompose some tensor products of semi-simple Lie algebra representations into irreducibles. I've read great things about [Lie](http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/%7Emaavl/LiE/) but I get a "502 Bad Gateway" when I use the online demonstration. Does anyone know of any other ways to fix this?

I tried to download it but was not tech savvy enough to succeed. Running the program online would be preferable, if possible.

Comment: Instead of Lie you could use LieART, which is very well documented. Furthermore, these computations have been done already, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decomposition of tensor products for representations of semisimple Lie algebras has been computed for many cases, with LieART, see

[LieART 2.0 – A Mathematica Application for Lie Algebras and Representation Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.10969.pdf).

In section $5$, extensive tables can be found with the results. I suppose you can find your answers there. Furthermore the authors explain how to compute it with LieART 2.0 within Mathematica.